# How to get multipart Parameters from HTTPServletRequest to create a swagger object to trace coverage contract test

Tags: java, filter

I'm building a filter to trace the coverage about contract test.
My java Filter is:

```
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest servletRequest, final ServletResponse servletResponse, final FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
MultiReadHttpServletRequest cacheReq = new MultiReadHttpServletRequest((HttpServletRequest)servletRequest);
MultiReadHttpServletResponse cacheResp = new MultiReadHttpServletResponse((HttpServletResponse)servletResponse);
log.info("Collecting coverage data open api 2 ...");
filterChain.doFilter(cacheReq, cacheResp);
Operation operation = new Operation();
ParameterMap parameterMap = this.retrieveParam.getPathParameter(cacheReq.getRequestURI(), cacheReq.getParameterMap());
```

I have a httpRequest object like (debug image from ide):

[image]

I have difficult to retrieve value from multipartFiles parameter in HttpServletRequest object. Is it possible to create a structure to retrieve this information?

Comment: Do you want a preview in IDE while debugging?

Comment: Hi @SheelPrabhakar, I need to create a Map o similar object with value of MultipartFiles that you can see in my debug images. I have difficult to retrieve value from multipartFiles parameter in HttpServletRequest object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to cast the request in MockMultipartHttpServletRequest object:

```
if (httpRequest instanceof MockMultipartHttpServletRequest) {
final MockMultipartHttpServletRequest mock = (MockMultipartHttpServletRequest) httpRequest ;
final List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
for (final Map.Entry<String, List<MultipartFile>> entry : mock.getMultiFileMap().entrySet()) {
    for (final MultipartFile file : entry.getValue()) {
        parts.add(file.getName());
    }
}
return parts;
```